# tensorflow on classifications

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I am currently learning the tensorflow. I have tried to make a model of classification using softmax model. 
In the program, I set the training data set on left hand side of two columns and two labels on right hand side of two columns in a CSV file. Such as:

Data1,Data2,label1,label2
 234,  23,    1,     0     #234 is bigger than 23, so label1 is tagged as 1, and label2 tagged as 0
 156,  113,   1,     0
  1,    4,    0,     1

It works to classify the testing data with the biggest number base on the training data set as above, and the cost value is converged to nearly zero.

However, I change the dataset to label the even number which aims at classifying the testing data in even number, the model fails, while the cost is fluctuating . The dataset is as following:

Data1,Data2,label1,label2
 24,  35,    1,     0     #24 is even number, so label1 is tagged as 1, and label2 tagged as 0
 156,  553,   1,     0
  1,    4,    0,     1

Am I wrong with the program? Why it works with distinguishing the biggest number among the dataset, while fail in even number? Thanks all!
Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np


def next_batch(num, data, labels):
    idx = np.arange(0 , len(data))
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    idx = idx[:num]
    data_shuffle = [data[ i] for i in idx]

    labels_shuffle = [labels[ i] for i in idx]
    return np.asarray(data_shuffle), np.asarray(labels_shuffle)

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

filename = dir_path + "/classification.csv"

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2]) 
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2]) 
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 2]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

pred =tf.add( tf.matmul(x, W),b)

cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred,labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer())

    with open(filename) as inf:
        # Skip header
        next(inf)
        result_array = np.shape(4)
        for line in inf:

            data1, data2,label1,label2= line.strip().split(",")

            data1 = float(data1)
            data2 = float(data2)
            label1 = int(label1)
            label2 = int(label2)
            result_array = np.append(result_array, (data1,data2,label1,label2))

    result_array=result_array.reshape(1000,4)
    k=result_array[:,2:4]
    gg=result_array[:,0:2] 
    for i in range(0,3000):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = next_batch(200,gg,k)  

        h,cos=sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs,y:batch_ys})
        print(cos)

    print(sess.run(pred,feed_dict={x:[[5,2],[4,9],[4,3],[5,2],[3,6],[30,21],[32,20],[3,4]]})) #testing data
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have a single layer of neurons, which means your network can only solve linearly separable problems.  Determining whether an integer is even or odd isn't linearly separable (you can't plot all integers and draw a single line between the even and the odd ones).

Try adding another layer which takes the output of the first layer as input and train that network instead. You will need more than a single output from the first layer though. Two or three might be enough. It's enough for XOR, but I haven't tried this particular problem.